# Get firebase object with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to get a firebase object using Angular, which I am successful in doing. However, I'm not sure how I would traverse any deeper in what is returning (picture below).

[What is returning now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqj9c.png) and
[My Firebase object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNF3d.png)

Here is how I got here:

**ClientService**

```
getClientsOfThisBranch(branchNumber:string){
   return this.db.list('/clients/' + branchNumber).snapshotChanges();
}
```

**SomeComponent**

```
clientInfo$: any[] = [];

this.clientService.getClientsOfThisBranch('17').subscribe(data => {
   data.forEach(x => { console.log( x.payload.val() ); this.clientInfo$.push(x.payload.val())})
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With what I can understand from your question, is you are trying to convert the returned data into an array of clientInfo. You are getting the data as an object of client id containing client info. You can use `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` to traverse deeper.

```
clientInfo: any[];

this.clientService.getClientsOfThisBranch('17').subscribe(data => {
  this.clientInfo = data.map(x => { 
    let obj = x.payload.val();
    let id = Object.keys(obj)[0];  //Assuming only 1 item as per image posted
    let info = Object.values(obj)[0];   //Assuming only 1 item as per image posted
    console.log(id, info);
  })
});
```

If you have more than one value, you can iterate them.